# How to output a newline character to a binary file in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

```
fstream file("newdata.txt",ios::out | ios::binary);
char word = {'a','e','i','o','u'};
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
 file.write(&word[i],sizeof(word[i]));
 file<<"\n";
}
```

I am trying to write all the vowels to a binary file with each vowel in one line. But the newline is always ignored. I have tried file.put('\n') as well, but it never worked. Any way out? Thanks for taking your time.

Comment: Why are you writing text to a binary file? Wouldn't it be easier to open it in text mode (the default) and just write text to it normally (like `file << word[i] << '\n';`)?

Comment: As for your problem, I guess you're on a Windows system? Where newlines are really `"\r\n"`.

Comment: When I fix your syntax error (`char word[]`), [the program works fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7072e67ee08adea6). Show us the code you're _actually_ using; show us your [MCVE]. How did you attempt to observe these newlines? Did you do so by opening your file in a text editor on Windows? Does that text editor understand `'\n'` line endings? If not, the problem is not with your program and you have not correctly identified where the problem is, merely assuming that the newline "is ignored". Examine the actual bytes of the file instead then focus on what that tells you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It works fine because that site tests on Linux where binary and text files are the same thing.

Comment: @interjay: Thank you, I am aware of how newlines work on Linux. Again, I am trying to guide this individual towards an understanding. Perhaps you could take the energy you're expending teaching me the basics of computers and spend it on writing a useful answer instead?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If you are aware, then you are being deliberately obtuse and misleading in claiming this program "works fine" when you know that it's incorrect. Maybe you could try writing a useful answer yourself instead of pointless comments?

Comment: @interjay: The program, as it is written, absolutely _does_ "work fine" - it is written to inject newlines and I have shown that the newlines are indeed present. What is wrong is (presumably) the OP's observation and analysis of where the problem lies, not inspecting the result in an accurate/useful fashion. If you could find it within yourself to get off my back for a few minutes, perhaps we can teach the OP something here after all. Thank you.

Comment: @interjay binary and text files are the same thing on all platform. It's processing different by the library that access them. Technically on windows "\n" should generate two characters (so when you copy file to Linux, you'll see ^M at line ends). But using mingw, Cygwin or their analogs on Windows leads to confusing results, program writes only one character - \n. some editors, e.g. notepad, ignore single \n, while others read it correctly as end of line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is a binary file (because you asked for one in line 1), so newlines are not any special. In binary files, you are writing bytes, not text.

Try changing `ios::binary` to the respective text-file constant, and it should work.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It "worked", but didn't write the correct newline format for OP's platform.

Comment: @interjay: I am trying to prompt this author to expand their answer so that it actually addresses the question.